# is there some sort of scope resolution operator to get to a name outside the class

Tags: dart

In the following code I would like the function *globalFoo* to access the file level *foo*. What is the way to do that?

```dart
class Foo {
  foo() => print('Foo.foo');
  globalFoo() => foo();  // How to call top level foo?
}

foo() => print('Global.foo');

main() {
  final foo = new Foo();
  foo.globalFoo();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an alias :

```dart
class Foo {
  foo() => print('Foo.foo');
  globalFoo() => _foo();
}

foo() => print('Global.foo');
final _foo = foo;  // Alias foo with _foo

main() {
  final foo = new Foo();
  foo.globalFoo();
}
```